# Return a local reference from function

Tags: c++, reference

I'm trying to understand what's going on inside with this (weird?) g++ behavior.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int& f(void) {
  int a = 9;
  int& b = a;
  return a;
}
int main(void) {
  int& l = f();

  cout << ++l << '\n' << l << '\n';
}
```

When returning `a` itself and bind it to `l`, I get a warning (reference to local variable) and a seg.fault if I acess it from l, but when returning `b` itself not only do I not get a seg.fault but I can access it once from l (UB I am guessing) before the value of l randomly changes. But what exactly happens here?

Aren't the two returns identical? Does g++ automatically mark `a's` area as unusable after the return, hence the seg.fault while for some reason allowing b to live longer?

Comment: It's UB. Either inspect the exact, generated assembly or don't try to guess. There is no general explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main question is why gcc doesn't issue a warning in one of the alternatives. Both alternatives are undefined behavior and the only difference is that in one case the compiler can detect it and warn you about it.

The C++ standard does not require a diagnostic for undefined behavior. Any diagnostic to that effect, from your compiler, is just an extra bonus; and although modern C++ compilers are very smart, they can't always figure out that the compiled code [will result in demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

P.S. gcc 10.2 does issue a warning with the `-O3` option, for the `return b;` alternative. With `-Wall` only, gcc also issues ***a 2nd*** warning for undefined behavior, you can discover what it is by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I also found out `clang` warns as well, which is interesting!

Answer (score 2):

No, C++ compilers do not mark areas as unusable.

Segfaults are just one of many ways undefined behavior can exhibit itself.  It is in fact one of the friendlier ways, as it makes you notice it early.

You are in charge of lifetime.  If you get it wrong, the result is undefined behavior.  Not an exception.  Not a segfault.  **Literally anything**.

One possibly symptom is "it appears to work".  Another is segfault.  Others include literal time travel (where UB later in the program makes ealier code behave differently), your computer hard drive being rendered unusable, someone getting your credit card information, your browser history being emailed to your contact list, etc.

Some compilers, in debug mode, mark deallocated memory with a bit pattern to aid debugging.

Comment: However, the two return statements are identical, right?  So I am guessing returning the ref itself doesn't give a warning/seg.fault because it could also be pointing to something with a life scope greater than the function?

Comment: @pol One is easy for the compiler to diagnose, the other one slightly harder.  But they are both UB (once you use the returned reference).  Compiler warnings are just warnings, they are not guaranteed nor comprehensive of every problem.

Answer (score 1):

> But what exactly happens here?

Undefined behaviour.

> Aren't the two returns identical?

The source code is clearly syntactically different. The programs don't have same semantic meaning because neither program has any semantic meaning because the meaning of the both programs is undefined. As such, the behaviour of the programs is not guaranteed to be the same.

> Does g++ automatically mark a's area as unusable after the return

Perhaps. I wouldn't assume this to be the case based on that one observation but this may be true. See the source code of GCC to confirm.